# AG Grid rowDrag Rows being dragged takes up full width of screen

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a table which is imported, with a scss with 100% width. The tables size is controlled by divs. When rowdrag is enabled in that table and a row is dragged the row goes to full width of the screen. If i change AG Grids scss to a smaller size of overflow: hidden it becomes a bit shorter, but still much wider than the grid itself.
unsure what code is helpful to add here. This is my ag grid that I import. The dragging is working its just looking a bit awful.

```
function AgGridClientSide({ handleRowSelection, data, handleCellEdited, tableColumnDef, rowHeight, onGridReady }) {
const gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: tableColumnDef,
    rowSelection: 'single',
    rowHeight,
    onCellValueChanged(params) {
        handleCellEdited(params);
    },
};

return (
    <div className="ag-theme-material">
        <AgGridReact
            gridOptions={gridOptions}
            rowData={data}
            onGridReady={onGridReady}
            onRowClicked={current => handleRowSelection(current)}
            suppressCellSelection
            suppressNoRowsOverlay
            rowDragManaged
            animateRows
        />
    </div>
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is only a quick fix.
You can assign a width css property using this:

```
.ag-dnd-ghost.ag-unselectable.ag-theme-alpine {
    width: 100px;
}
```